# Ошибка [CRITICAL] [App ] Unable to get a Window, abort. в python kivy

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, kivy

Я установил kivy как написано в офф документации но при запуске скрипта выдаётся такая ошибка:

```
  egor@egor-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~/codes/x_0$ python3 main.py
    [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/egor/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-05-28_4.txt
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
    [GCC 8.2.0]
    [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
    [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
    [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
    [INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
    [CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
    egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name 'bcm'
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
        fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
        from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

    sdl2 - TypeError: expected bytes, str found
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
        cls = cls()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 138, in __init__
        super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 722, in __init__
        self.create_window()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 237, in create_window
        self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
      File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 94, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window (kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:2204)

    x11 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11'
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
        fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

    [CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже на то, что вы либо установили старую версию, либо установка прошла с ошибкой или часть модулей не установилась.
Этому свидетельствуют сообщения из лога ошибки:

> x11 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11'
>
> egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name 'bcm'

Попробуйте запустить установку всех пакетов kivy заново, выполнив команду:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git@master
```

Идентичный вопрос на [английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529794/x11-importerror-no-module-named-kivy-core-window-window-x11).